# How to disable services with WebApplicationFactory

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, integration-testing

I'm adding integration tests to a ASP.NET Core web service (see Microsoft's article on [Integration tests in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests) and I've extended `WebApplicationFactory` to replace the Database provider with the in-memory database.  However, the ASP.NET Core web service includes other services that are enabled by default.

Each service can be stopped/disabled through the service object, but calls to `GetRequiredService()` on `WebApplicationFactory.ConfigureServices()` throw `System.InvalidOperationException`.

Does anyone know if there is a way to disable default services?

Comment: Register mocks that replace the default services so calls to `GetRequiredService<T>()` will resolve your mocked services.

Comment: You need to not register them in the first place. Factor out the registrations that you need to vary into virtual methods on your `Startup` class. Then in your test project, you can create a `TestStartup` class, inherit from the SUT's `Startup` class and override those methods to do different things.

Comment: That said, outright disabling services in an integration test pretty much defeats the entire point of an integration test. You're now no longer working with the same setup as you actual app, so passing tests tell you nothing about the actual state of your app. It's okay to substitute providers (i.e. in-memory instead of SQL Server for your database), but the actual service should still be there in some form or another.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
var service = services.FirstOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(IService));
if (service != null)
{
    services.Remove(service);
}
```

In your CustomWebApplication factory in the scope of

```
builder.ConfigureTestServices(services => ...)
```

Comment: If you wanted to remove all `HostedService` registrations, do the following...

`.ConfigureTestServices(services => { services.RemoveAll<IHostedService>(); })
`

Answer (score 0):

Just setup your integration test like this:

Try this:

```cs
IHostBuilder hostBuilder = // Create from production code
IHost host = await hostBuilder
    .ConfigureWebHost(web => {
        web.UseTestServer();
        web.ConfigureTestServices(svc => {
            svc.RemoveAll<IHostedService>();
        });
    })
    .StartAsync();

HttpClient client = _testHost.GetTestServer().CreateClient();

// Use client to make HTTP requests
```